# SQL query to return all rows where one or more of the fields contains a certain value

Tags: sql

Is it possible to run a select on a table to quickly find out if **any** (one or more) of the fields contain a certain value?

Or would you have to write out all of the column names in the where clause?

Comment: I swear I saw this question yesterday, but I can't find it.

Comment: Give us more information. Expand your question, just click edit and do it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dig this... It will search on all the tables in the db, but you can mod it down to just one table.

```
/*This script will find any text value in the database*/
/*Output will be directed to the Messages window. Don't forget to look there!!!*/

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @valuetosearchfor varchar(128), @objectOwner varchar(64)
SET @valuetosearchfor = '%staff%' --should be formatted as a like search 
SET @objectOwner = 'dbo'

DECLARE @potentialcolumns TABLE (id int IDENTITY, sql varchar(4000))

INSERT INTO @potentialcolumns (sql)
SELECT 
    ('if exists (select 1 from [' +
    [tabs].[table_schema] + '].[' +
    [tabs].[table_name] + 
    '] (NOLOCK) where [' + 
    [cols].[column_name] + 
    '] like ''' + @valuetosearchfor + ''' ) print ''SELECT * FROM [' +
    [tabs].[table_schema] + '].[' +
    [tabs].[table_name] + 
    '] (NOLOCK) WHERE [' + 
    [cols].[column_name] + 
    '] LIKE ''''' + @valuetosearchfor + '''''' +
    '''') as 'sql'
FROM information_schema.columns cols
    INNER JOIN information_schema.tables tabs
        ON cols.TABLE_CATALOG = tabs.TABLE_CATALOG
            AND cols.TABLE_SCHEMA = tabs.TABLE_SCHEMA
            AND cols.TABLE_NAME = tabs.TABLE_NAME
WHERE cols.data_type IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nvchar', 'nvarchar','text','ntext')
    AND tabs.table_schema = @objectOwner
    AND tabs.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY tabs.table_catalog, tabs.table_name, cols.ordinal_position

DECLARE @count int
SET @count = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @potentialcolumns)
PRINT 'Found ' + CAST(@count as varchar) + ' potential columns.'
PRINT 'Beginning scan...'
PRINT ''
PRINT 'These columns contain the values being searched for...'
PRINT ''
DECLARE @iterator int, @sql varchar(4000)
SET @iterator = 1
WHILE @iterator <= (SELECT Max(id) FROM @potentialcolumns)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = (SELECT [sql] FROM @potentialcolumns where [id] = @iterator)
    IF (@sql IS NOT NULL) and (RTRIM(LTRIM(@sql)) <> '')
    BEGIN
        --SELECT @sql --use when checking sql output
        EXEC (@sql)
    END
    SET @iterator = @iterator + 1
END

PRINT ''
PRINT 'Scan completed'
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you're likely going to have to write all the columns into your WHERE clause, either by hand or programatically.  SQL does not include functionality to do it directly.  A better question might be "why do you need to do this?".  Needing to use this type of query is possibly a good indicator that your database isn't properly [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  If you tell us your schema, we may be able to help with that problem too (if it's an actual problem).

Comment: +1 - I can imagine situations where you might have the same value in more than one column but you are right: it smells like bad design.  Of course, the risk of this is all the higher when the question is so basic.

Comment: Code smell here indicates what rmeador points out...Is your db structured for what you are doing with it?

Comment: I sometimes have to run queries against mainframe systems with tons of fields where the field names are random eight character strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to list all the columns in the where clause.  I'm far from a SQL wizard though...maybe someone else knows a way.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to write it out

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to write out all columns you want to use as a criteria.

If you add what programming language you are using and in what type of environment you working we can give you a clue or solution of how to do it dynamically.

I think your question really was how to do this dynamically depending of what the user of your program fill in in the "search"-form.. Im right?

If not, then.. Give us more information. ;)